# How can I send mass mail without spam

Tags: magento-1.9

I am working on a functionality to send mass `mail` on `product update`.I want to improve code for `performance` and to avoid `spam`.

**Code:**

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->getCollection();
 $arr = array();

   foreach ($collection as $subscriber) 
   {
      $arr[] = $subscriber->getData();
   }

    $html = '<strong>Dear Subscriber,</strong><br>
                    Following product has been updated <br><br> ';

      for($j=0;$j<count($arr);$j++)
      {
         $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
             ->setToName($arr[$j]['subscriber_email'])
             ->setToEmail($arr[$j]['subscriber_email'])
             ->setBody($html)
             ->setSubject('Sarees Images Collection')
             ->setFromEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email', $storeId))
             ->setFromName(Mage::app()->getStore()->getName())
             ->setType('html');
             try{

             $mail->send();
             }
             catch(Exception $error)
             {
             Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($error->getMessage());
             return false;
             }
         }
```

**Problem:**

Though mails are being sent to susbscribers it is slowing the page and there is a fear of being spammed.

How can I tackle this?

I am using `Magento ver. 1.9.2.4`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the webserver where you host your website for bulk mailing is not a very good idea. Spamfilters will add you to blacklists which could eventually harm your website in unexpected ways.

If you want to send bulk emails from your magento use an Email provider instead. They have dedicated teams to stay out of spamboxes so you don't have to worry about that anymore. There are plenty free solutions like [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/), [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/) (trough [Mandrill](https://mandrillapp.com/)) and [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/). Mailgun is developers oriented, so that might be a good choice.

Check a [roundup here](http://www.codeinwp.com/blog/mandrill-alternatives/).

Comment: ok..if I hv around 500 `email` addresses,how can I improve the `code` esp. `loop` part?

Comment: If it is slowing pageload too much you could consider it moving it to solving it with a cronjob? Write code which does a check who should be email when cronjob is running.

Comment: You mean in batch process?

Comment: Yes, see example here: http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-cron-script-in-magento/